# Strange feedback in an array when I switch from int to double

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, int

I'm new to C++, and doing my first array lab. I've successfully formatted and displayed what I wanted, but I did so using ints - when the object of it was to have all the numbers be floating point numbers. I changed the array type to double, along with the corresponding functions.. and now when I try to print out some numbers (the number 100 in this case) it gives me weird feedback.

I've looked around and the only cause I can find of strange numbers in arrays is not initializing the array. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel as if I've done that (considering the output when I use int is what I want minus the decimal places.) Yet when I switch from INT to DOUBLE - I get weird feedback.

This is my program with double. (strange numbers)

```
void print(double twenty_by_twenty[][SIZE])

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        cout << right << setw(5) << setprecision(2) << twenty_by_twenty[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}




void initialize_array(double twenty_by_twenty[][SIZE])

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (j > 0 && j < 19 && i == 0 || j > 0 && j < 19 && i == 19)
        {
            twenty_by_twenty[i][j] = { 100 };
        }
        else
        {
            twenty_by_twenty[i][j] = { 0 };
        }
    }
}



int main()

double twenty_by_twenty[20][20];

initialize_array(twenty_by_twenty);

print(twenty_by_twenty);
```

This is my program with int. (displays what I want - no decimal places)

```
void print(int twenty_by_twenty[][SIZE])

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        cout << right << setw(5) << setprecision(2) << twenty_by_twenty[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}




void initialize_array(int twenty_by_twenty[][SIZE])

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (j > 0 && j < 19 && i == 0 || j > 0 && j < 19 && i == 19)
        {
            twenty_by_twenty[i][j] = { 100 };
        }
        else
        {
            twenty_by_twenty[i][j] = { 0 };
        }
    }
}



int main()

int twenty_by_twenty[20][20];

initialize_array(twenty_by_twenty);

print(twenty_by_twenty);
```

Comment: How is `SIZE` defined?

Comment: You don't use arrays for this in C++. Switch to `std::vector` and all will be good.

Comment: What is the strange output you get, and how does it differ from the output you want?

Comment: What is weird feedback?  What is it displaying and what are you expecting it to display?

Comment: SIZE is defined as 20 = the size of the 2D array, which is a square. They told us we're not allowed to use vectors yet.. 

And for every "100" it tries to print out it prints out 1e+002. It prints out the zeroes fine.

Comment: I want a box with 0.0 on the edges, 100.0 on the top (save the corners) and 0.0 for the rest of them. But I can't get any decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on your comments: you asked for a precision of 2.  By default, `std::cout` uses scientific notation if the value of the exponent in scientific notation would be less than the precision, and greater than or equal -4, and fixed otherwise.  I suspect that what you want is fixed precision; in which case, you have to tell the the stream so: `std::cout << fixed <<...`.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing your numbers with `setprecision(2)`

When using an int, this will not change its value. I.e: it will print 100

Using double, however it will use [precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/), in this case 2, so 1e+02

You probably want something like, using [`fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/):

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << twenty_by_twenty[i][j]; // 100.00
```

[`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/):

> Sets the decimal precision to be used to format **floating-point** values on output operations.